# Moq with Func<Foo, Task<List<Bar>>>>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Scenario:

We are in the lovely scenario of a terrible data source that requires an arcane syntax. We have built our "repository" layer to translate simple parameters (primitive values) into the correct syntax for the destination.

We would like to unit test that:

1. The correct filters have been applied (can be done by checking the string that the repo's helper methods create)
2. The (mocked) remote data source is called exactly once
3. The (mocked) data we have defined the remote data source as returning is passed back as the return value when we call the repo.

For example

```
var expectedReturn = new List<Product> { new Product { StockNumber = "123" } };

provider.Setup(x => x.Run(It.IsAny<Func<IRemoteClient, Task<List<Product>>>>(),
    It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(expectedReturn);
```

Moq is failing on the `Setup` line with a `NotSupportedException`. I've read probably a dozen or more SO posts and can't find out why it doesn't work.

In normal usage, the Repo will use something like:

```
provider.Run(x => x.GetAsync<List<Product>>(requestBuilder.Request), "foo")
```

Definition of run in `provider` interface:

```
Task<T> Run<T>(Func<IRemoteClient, Task<T>> action, string name);
```

Since the requestBuilder is injected as well, we can easily evaluate that the request is built correctly as far as the number and type of parameters, but we can't run the test at all because the `Mock` call fails the setup and so we never get there.

Comment: what if you rather do `.Returns(Task.FromResult(expectedReturn))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Moq 4.9.0 and have tested this both on .NET Core 2.1, as well as inside LINQPad using the .NET Framework. It compiles and runs for me without any problems. I am able to run the mock setup, and I am also able to call the mocked method on the mock object, and retrieve the expected return result.

The following is my test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expectedReturn = new List<Product> { new Product { StockNumber = "123" } };

        var provider = new Mock<IProvider>();
        provider
            .Setup(x => x.Run(
                It.IsAny<Func<IRemoteClient, Task<List<Product>>>>(),
                It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expectedReturn);

        var result = provider.Object.Run(client => client.GetAsync<List<Product>>(null), "foo");

        Console.WriteLine(result.Result[0].StockNumber);
    }
}

public interface IProvider
{
    Task<T> Run<T>(Func<IRemoteClient, Task<T>> action, string name);
}
public interface IRemoteClient
{
    Task<T> GetAsync<T>(object request);
}
public class Product
{
    public string StockNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My oversimplified example wound up having some other problems, it seems. You're correct this seems to work. I wound up deciding that `Run()` really didn't need to take `Func<>` anyway and refactoring around that.